# Authorization to share the following types is disallowed: HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth in swift ios 8.4

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit, hkhealthstore

Authorization to share the following types is disallowed: HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth,HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex in swift ios version 8.4

```
healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToRead, readTypes: healthKitTypesToWrite, completion: { (success, error) -> Void in

                if( completion != nil )
                {
                    completion(success:success,error:error)
                }

            })
```

Returns the types of data that Fit wishes to write to HealthKit.

```
    func dataTypesToWrite() -> NSSet {

        var dietaryCalorieEnergyType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryEnergyConsumed) as HKQuantityType
        var activeEnergyBurnType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned) as HKQuantityType
        var heightType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight) as HKQuantityType
        var weightType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass) as HKQuantityType

        var set = Set([dietaryCalorieEnergyType, activeEnergyBurnType, heightType, weightType])

        return set//[NSSet setWithObjects:dietaryCalorieEnergyType, activeEnergyBurnType, heightType, weightType, nil];
    }
```

Returns the types of data that Fit wishes to read from HealthKit.

```
    func dataTypesToRead()->NSSet {
        var dietaryCalorieEnergyType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDietaryEnergyConsumed) as HKQuantityType
        var activeEnergyBurnType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierActiveEnergyBurned) as HKQuantityType
        var heightType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeight) as HKQuantityType
        var weightType = HKObjectType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBodyMass) as HKQuantityType
        var birthdayType = HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierDateOfBirth) as HKCharacteristicType
        var biologicalSexType = HKObjectType.characteristicTypeForIdentifier(HKCharacteristicTypeIdentifierBiologicalSex) as HKCharacteristicType

        var set = Set([dietaryCalorieEnergyType, activeEnergyBurnType, heightType, weightType, birthdayType, biologicalSexType])

        return set
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The arguments to `requestAuthorizationToShareTypes` are reversed.  Try this instead:

```
healthKitStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(healthKitTypesToWrite, readTypes: healthKitTypesToRead, completion: { (success, error) -> Void in

    if( completion != nil )
    {
        completion(success:success,error:error)
    }
})
```